# Get specific Class from a package including sub packages

Tags: java, java-6

I have the need of getting the `Class` from a `String`.
The string is just the class his name without the package declaration.

While I could use `Class.forName(className);` this requires me to give the FQN.

Here is just where I have the problem.
I know its base package : `be.chillworld.catalog` but this package have subpackages.

Example :

- `be.chillworld.catalog.location`
- `be.chillworld.catalog.operation`

Easiest solution is to remove all the subpackages so I can do the `Class.forName()` but there goes the nice structure then.

Anyone have an idea of how to get mine specific class?

Comment: If you know that is has to be in one of these subpackages (assuming that this is always the case), why don't you try both?

Comment: it's a bit more subpackages then 2 (I minimalize the problem for asking) but it's an idea

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: Did read that before, but then I still have to search in the collection of Classes to se witch is the one I want. Your first comment is in mine eye's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflections Class.Give base package when initiating class and get your specific classes.

Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.sss.xxx");

reflection.getSubTypesOf(ddd.class)

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: I don't have a `ddd.class`, I'm just searching for the `ddd.class` with the string `ddd`

Comment: Here ddd i.e. class name .Replcae that with your class name and ""com.sss.xxx" is the base package name .In you rcase it's be.chillworld.catalog